# ASMifier class missing from ASM 3.3.1

Tags: java, fedora, java-bytecode-asm

According to [the ASM FAQ](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q10), to get example ASM code, I should use the `ASMifier` class, like this:

```
java -classpath "asm.jar;asm-util.jar" org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier org/domain/package/YourClass.class
```

But that gets me the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier
```

Looking at JAR files, the `ASMifier` class seems to be missing, though its helper classes are present:

```
./org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifierClassVisitor.class
./org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifierAnnotationVisitor.class
./org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifierMethodVisitor.class
./org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifierAbstractVisitor.class
./org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifierFieldVisitor.class
```

This is with ASM 3.3.1, as provided by Fedora 20.  Is the FAQ for a newer version, and I should be using different instructions?  Did Fedora mess up the packaging (even though their bug-tracker shows nothing)?  Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When browsing the SVN repository of ASM, you can read up the [revision history of the `ASMifier`](http://websvn.ow2.org/log.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fasm%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2Futil%2FASMifier.java&sr=1735&er=1&max=100&search=&all=1): It was [formerly known as the `ASMifierClassVisitor`](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftags%2FASM_3_3_1%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2Futil%2FASMifierClassVisitor.java&peg=1529) which was also this utility's name in version 3.1.1.

ASM never had a reputation of maintaining binary or even compilation compatibility. Thus, you might encounter several problems like the one you describe when using non-bleeding edge versions of the library. (The authors promised to improve this after ASM's version four.) You, or the libraries that you use, should however always repackage ASM into a different namespace in order to avoid such issues. This is even [recommended in the FAQ to using ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q15).

For running your example, you would have to use:

```
java -classpath "asm.jar;asm-util.jar" \
    org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifierClassVisitor \
    org/domain/package/YourClass.class
```